# Deterministic compile time mapping function for MemoryPool

Tags: c++, c++14, hashtable, memory-pool

please refer to the picture below where I tried to show what I am trying to implement:
[image]

There are several memory `Partition`s statically allocated in the memory containing `chunks` of various sizes, known at the compile time. Each partition has `chunks` of different size. The `Partition` implements the `IPartition` interface. The pointers `IPartition *` are organized within the C-style array where `idx` is an index to that array in range of `0..nPartitions`.

In my custom `operator new(size_t size)` implementation I am about to use the concept described above to return a memory chunk of appropriate size where the type of any size will fit. The obvious requirement is the chunk size must be equal or bigger than the size of the type.

**GOAL / TASK/ QUESTION:**

I need to design a function `constexpr unsigned int func( size_t size )` which takes the `size` of the object to be allocated and returns the index `idx` to the array of `IPartition *` pointers which points to the "right" Partition having chunks of appropriate `size`.

To make things more complicated, the `func()` must take a constant time to keep the whole memory allocation using memory pool **deterministic**.

The whole thing points me to `std::unordered_map` but the target system is small MCU limited in resources. Maybe the solution could be a hash table where the hashes are calculated at compile time (num of Partitions as well as chunk sizes are known at compile time), I do not know...

I would be very happy if someone could help me to follow the optimal way of doing so...

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: looks like you should take a look in this [cppCon talk](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U). You will see there pasterns which should be helpful for you.

Comment: @MarekR Do you have any concrete pattern in mind I should look for?

Comment: "To make things more complicated, the `func()` must take a constant time to keep the whole memory allocation using memory pool deterministic." I don't see how these two things relate. What does taking "constant time" (do you mean `O(1)`?) have to do with determinism?

Comment: @MaxLanghof In general any allocation using memory pool must take a predictable amount of time. So it should not be dependent on how many partitions there are, etc. It is more or less the opposite approach to malloc() where it is completely unpredictable how long it takes to get the pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: Ah, you mean that the allocation time is predictable, not that the program output is deterministic. I see.

Comment: What is the reason you can't just design `func` as a series of `if (size < x) return y; else ...` statements? Or are these values known at compile time but not at "code time"?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Exactly. The simplest approach would be to iterate over all the partitions and checking whether the object fits the size of the chunk or not. For example in case of small object, maybe it fits to the first partition having the smallest chunks while some large object must "ask" many partitions "where to fit". Long story short everytime a path of different length to go. I need exactly the opposite.

Comment: I thought about implementation of a kind of hash function which is pre-calculated at compile time providing the mapping "object size" --> "partition chunk size". But I do not know how to implement such...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174725/discussion-between-max-langhof-and-martin-kopecky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a binary search for the size. This is a constant number of instructions to each return, `O(log(N))` in the number of partitions and only mildly annoying to write by hand. For your four chunk sizes that would be:

```
constexpr unsigned int func( size_t size )
{
  if (size <= 4)
    if (size <= 3)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1;
  else
    if (size <= 8)
      return 2;
    else
      return 3;
}
```

It should also be possible to template-metaprogram this given a (sorted) list of compile-time sizes, but I don't know if that's your use case.

Comment: Many thanks Max. I think the binary search is the right path to follow. I am going to try the concrete implementation. Thanks again for your effort to help!